# Can anyone identify this distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, density-function

I'm given a pdf in a different form and asked to identify the random variable. Also, there is a positive constant $c$ that i have to identify.

PDF: $f(x)= c*\exp(-x^2-x/4)\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R} $

I suspect this is the normal distribution but I am not sure.

I have tried to factor the exponent by adding and subtracting 1/64

$$
\begin{align}
c\ \exp(-x^2-x/4)&=c\ \exp(-(x^2+x/4+1/64-1/64))\\
&=c\ \exp(-(x^2+x/4+1/64)+1/64)\\
&=c\ \exp(-(x+1/8)(x+1/8)+1/64)\\
&=c\ \exp(-(x+1/8)(x+1/8))*\exp(1/64)\\
&=c\exp(1/64)\exp\big(-(x+1/8)(x+1/8)\big)
\end{align}
$$

but I keep getting stuck. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If the domain is the real line, and the term in the exponent is quadratic with leading coefficient negative, it's *always* normal. Take out a $-\frac12$ in the exponent, complete the square to find the parameters and then the required normalizing constant will be obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) = c\ \exp({-x^2-\frac{x}{4}}) &= c\ \exp({-(x+\frac{1}{8})^2+\frac{1}{64}})\\
&= c' \exp(-\frac{y^2}{2})\ \forall -\infty < y < \infty
\end{align}
$$

where $c'=c\ \exp(\frac{1}{64})$ and $y^2=2(x+\frac{1}{8})^2$

$f(y) = c'\ \exp(-\frac{y^2}{2})\ \forall -\infty < y < \infty$ is analogous(assuming $c$ should be such that $f(x)$ is a valid PDF) to a [standard normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution)

and hence $c' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ $\implies$ $c = \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{64}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Comment: For future reference -- with questions that could well be homework (or worse, on a test/exam), please lean toward [hints and guidance](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) rather than present fully worked (or nearly so) solutions.